# Do OpenGraph Actions have to be approved before they can be used in testing?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

I've created an open graph action, and so far I can only seem to use it to post the test page that Facebook has generated for me (I'm messing around with curl and a webserver serving the correct kinds of metadata).

Is this a restriction on actions (where, for sandboxed applications, only actions which have been approved can post real updates to a timeline), or am I likely looking at a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the app dashboard, you can create roles. Create one test user. After you log in from the test user (that will log you out from your original account), you can test freely. Or else, you can not post for global users unless your actions are submitted (via app dashboard -> open graph) and approved.